# how to terminate process with ebpf?

Tags: linux, kernel, kill-process, ebpf, execve

I want to send_sig_info to a process from inside bpf function (execve) but it won't load.
I know that they added a helper function since kernel 5.3 but I'm working on a lower kernel.
Is there a way to kill a process from bpf function?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to the `bpf_send_signal` helper, introduced in Linux v5.3. As far as I know, before that helper was introduced, **there was no way to terminate a process from a BPF program**.

If you are trying to kill the current process from it's `execve(2)` execution, you may be able to rely on seccomp-bpf instead. Note that, since seccomp-bpf relies on cBPF instead of eBPF, you won't be able to filter on the arguments (on purpose, because of the risk of TOCTTOU attacks).

Comment: I know that `bpf_send_signal` is from kernel v5.3, but there are other ways to send signal to process from kernel, they're just not supported inside eBFF. When I call them the bpf doesn't load my function, maybe there's a way to override their check?

Comment: What do you mean by "you won't be able to filter on the arguments" ?

Comment: I mean you can't dereference pointers in cBPF and all of execve's arguments are pointers. Could you detail what other ways of sending signals to process you are referring to?

Comment: with `struct siginfo` and `send_sig_info`

Comment: You can't use those from BPF.